# Firebase Recycler ValueEventListener returns last child only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to retrieve data from the `ValueEventListener`, and add this data to dialog and show it to the user, but it returns only the last child and I made a toast for the key of the item clicked and it returns the correct key

I am trying to retrieve this node

[image: Firebase Node]

**MainActivity**

```
public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private DatabaseReference payoutRef;
private Lead leadModel;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lead, PaymentViewHolder> adapter;
private Lead currentLead;

private String name;
private String contactPhone;
private String amount;
private String info;
private String purpose;
private String status;
private long actionDate;
private String paymentSanctioned;
private String payoutAmount;

private String current_user;
private String paidStatus;

private FirebaseAuth auth;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_activity, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.payment_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    current_user = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    payoutRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Payout");


    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.payment_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.payment_progress);


    return view;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

    }, 1000);


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lead, PaymentViewHolder>(
            Lead.class,
            R.layout.payment_item,
            PaymentViewHolder.class,
            payoutRef.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(current_user)
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PaymentViewHolder viewHolder, Lead model,  int position) {

            final String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.paymentText.setText(model.getName());


            payoutRef.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                        currentLead = dataSnapshot.getValue(Lead.class);

                        name = currentLead.getName();
                        contactPhone = currentLead.getContactPhone();
                        amount = currentLead.getAmount();
                        info = currentLead.getInfo();
                        purpose = currentLead.getPurpose();
                        status = currentLead.getStatus();
                        actionDate = currentLead.getActionDate();
                        paymentSanctioned = currentLead.getSanctionedPayment();
                        paidStatus = currentLead.getPaid();
                        payoutAmount = currentLead.getPayoutAmount();


                    }



                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.paymentCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), payoutAmount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Lead Information");
                    builder.setMessage(
                            "Name: " + name + "\n\n" +
                                    "Contact Phone: " + contactPhone + "\n\n" +
                                    "Amount: " + amount + "\n\n" +
                                    "Info: " + info + "\n\n" +
                                    "Purpose: " + purpose + "\n\n" +
                                    "Status: " + status + "\n\n" +
                                    "Action Date: " + getDate(actionDate) + "\n\n" +
                                    "Payment Sanctioned: " + paymentSanctioned + "\n\n" +
                                    "Payout Amount: " + payoutAmount + "\n\n" +
                                    "Paid Status: " + paidStatus + "\n\n"


                    );
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });


        }

    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


private String getDate(long actionDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    return sfd.format(new Date(actionDate));

}
```

**ValueEventListener**

```
 @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PaymentViewHolder viewHolder, Lead model,  int position) {

            final String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.paymentText.setText(model.getName());


            payoutRef.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                        currentLead = dataSnapshot.getValue(Lead.class);

                        name = currentLead.getName();
                        contactPhone = currentLead.getContactPhone();
                        amount = currentLead.getAmount();
                        info = currentLead.getInfo();
                        purpose = currentLead.getPurpose();
                        status = currentLead.getStatus();
                        actionDate = currentLead.getActionDate();
                        paymentSanctioned = currentLead.getSanctionedPayment();
                        paidStatus = currentLead.getPaid();
                        payoutAmount = currentLead.getPayoutAmount();


                    }



                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Lead {

private String name;
private String contactPhone;
private String amount;
private String info;
private String purpose;
private String status;
private long actionDate;
private String nextActionDate;
private String sanctionedPayment;
private String paid;
private String userId;
private String payoutAmount;
private String remarks;


public Lead() {

}

public Lead(String name, String contactPhone, String amount, String info, String purpose, String status, long actionDate, String nextActionDate, String sanctionedPayment, String paid, String userId, String payoutAmount, String remarks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.info = info;
    this.purpose = purpose;
    this.status = status;
    this.actionDate = actionDate;
    this.nextActionDate = nextActionDate;
    this.sanctionedPayment = sanctionedPayment;
    this.paid = paid;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.payoutAmount = payoutAmount;
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public String getPayoutAmount() {
    return payoutAmount;
}

public void setPayoutAmount(String payoutAmount) {
    this.payoutAmount = payoutAmount;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getPaid() {
    return paid;
}

public void setPaid(String paid) {
    this.paid = paid;
}

public long getActionDate() {
    return actionDate;
}

public void setActionDate(long actionDate) {
    this.actionDate = actionDate;
}

public String getNextActionDate() {
    return nextActionDate;
}

public void setNextActionDate(String nextActionDate) {
    this.nextActionDate = nextActionDate;
}

public String getSanctionedPayment() {
    return sanctionedPayment;
}

public void setSanctionedPayment(String sanctionedPayment) {
    this.sanctionedPayment = sanctionedPayment;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}


public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getContactPhone() {
    return contactPhone;
}

public void setContactPhone(String contactPhone) {
    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public String getPurpose() {
    return purpose;
}

public void setPurpose(String purpose) {
    this.purpose = purpose;
}
}
```

**ViewHolder Class**

```
public class PaymentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView paymentText;
public CardView paymentCardView;

public PaymentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    paymentText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.payment_item_name);
    paymentCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.payment_item_cardView);


}
```

Comment: Does your current user have only one payment?

Comment: no it contains two and every node contains a random key

Comment: What is the whole `payoutRef.child(key).addValueEventListener(` in `populateViewHolder` meant to accomplish? Why can't you just use the `Lead` that is passed in the `model` parameter? Note that in general there is quite a bit of code in your question, and it'll be easier to help if you isolate the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

just this code into your onDataChange method..

```
 if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                try {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Lead leadModel = postSnapshot.getValue(Lead.class);

                        if (leadModel!=null){
                            leadList.add(leadModel);
                            Log.e(" name is  ", "="+leadModel.getName());

                        }

                    }

                    adapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity().this, leadList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
```